# babel runtime helpers added with .js extension causing ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED in subpath that fail when running node 16

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am using `@babel/runtime` with the `useESModules: true` options and it is causing helpers to be emitted like this with the `.js` file extension

> `import "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends.js";`

This causes the following error:

> [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './helpers/esm/extends.js' is not defined by "exports" in `myproject/node_modules/@babel/runtime/package.json`

This is because this path conflicts with the `package.json` exports subpath pattern:

```json
"exports": {
  "./helpers/extends": [
  {
    "node": "./helpers/extends.js",
    "import": "./helpers/esm/extends.js",
    "default": "./helpers/extends.js"
   },
```

Removing the file extensions fixes this problem.

Is there any way to stop the file extensions from getting added?

My workaround is this, which is extremely hacky, and I run after every build:

```bash
sed -i -e s/'extends.js'/'extends'/g ./dist/server/entry-server.js
sed -i -e s/'assertThisInitialized.js'/'assertThisInitialized'/g ./dist/server/entry-server.js
sed -i -e s/'inheritsLoose.js'/'inheritsLoose'/g ./dist/server/entry-server.js
sed -i -e s/'wrapNativeSuper.js'/'wrapNativeSuper'/g ./dist/server/entry-server.js
sed -i -e s/'taggedTemplateLiteralLoose.js'/'taggedTemplateLiteralLoose'/g ./dist/server/entry-server.js
```